# Can you set multiple mbstring.language in php.ini?

Tags: php.ini

Can I set multiple mbstring.language in php.ini for multi-language websites? Or I have to set only one.

```
mbstring.language = English
mbstring.language = Japanese
mbstring.language = Korean
```

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.configuration.php#ini.mbstring.language

it seems that you can add multiple languages, doc doesn't help for that :P

but this one help:
http://marc.info/?l=php-i18n&m=107060346828334&w=2

from : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1691461/what-do-these-php-mbstring-settings-do